# How can I correct my arena simulation model

Tags: arena-simulation

I have an arena simulation model for coffee shop. Customer order is based on probability. 50%-1, 40%-2, 10%-3. Each drink is assigned a value. 90% of the customers are satisfied and leaves. 10% asks for remake, same drink is to be remade. How to do that?

[image]

How can I correct the model? Can I give condition in decide 2, if 1 go to coffee, 2 go to tea, 3 go to hot chocolate?